# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) \text{ exists}$

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve the following question:
$$\text{Let }f:(0,1) --> R\text{ be a differentiable function. Prove that if f' is bounded then } \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) \text{ exists}$$
What i tried:
I said that if $f$ is differentiable then the following limit exists: $\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \text{ for any x and y in (0,1)}$ and if $f'$ is bounded then there exists $\delta > 0 \text{ such that for any }  y-\delta<x<y+\delta:\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ is bounded too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists $M$  such that  $|f'(x)| \leq M$  for  all $x \in (0,1)$.

if  $x,y \in (0,1)$. By  mean value theorem, there is  $c$  in $(0,1)$ between $x$  and  $y$  such  that $f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)$ then : $$\forall x,y \in (0,1) \quad |f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|$$

let $(x_n)$ a sequence suche that $\lim x_n =0$ . For all $p,q \in \Bbb N$ we have: $$|f(x_p)-f(x_q)| \leq M|x_p-x_q|$$
Since $(x_n)$ converges it's a Cauchy's séquence then $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence too. then $f(x_n)$  converges .

Now if  $(x_n)$  and $(y_n)$  are sequences with limit $0$ let $L$  and  $L'$  the limits of  $f(x_n)$  and $f(y_n)$

We have  : $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \leq M|x_n-y_n|$$  for all $n \in \Bbb N$  then by limit : $$|L-L'| \leq 0$$  and  $$L=L'$$

All that shows that there exists $L \in \Bbb R$  such that for all sequence $(x_n)$ who converges to $0$  the qequence $(f(x_n))$  converges to $L$. that means that $$\lim_{0^+} f(x)=L$$